# Using Kdocker on startup (Arch Linux, KDE)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kde

I'm using [KDocker](https://github.com/user-none/KDocker) on startup to autostart Spotify in the system tray (since Spotify on Linux doesn't have that feature).

It works, however after startup the KDocker window selector (changing the cursor to a selector box with an X in it) starts up, and tries to dockify anything I click. I don't know why it's doing that, since I provided a startup command to it so it shouldn't be looking for user input. I can exit out of it using Escape, but it's still annoying. I'm using Kde, and set up this login script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Performing startup scripts"
echo "Starting Spotify docked"
kdocker -s -t -q -j -i /opt/spotify/icons/spotify-linux-64.png spotify
sleep 1
xdotool key Escape # to close out the annoying window picker that shows on startup
```

I attempted to use xdotool to automatically close out of the window selector, but it didn't work.

Any ideas of other ways I could avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[You can use XDG Autostart](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Autostart)

1. Edit the "Exec" line in your `/usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop` [as shown](https://gist.github.com/m4ttm/e15b18f37b6f77608774c3f4bcf2e708)
2. Copy this to `~/.config/autostart`
3. Reboot your system, Spotify should appear in the system tray

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The question is also about kdocker it seems, not just Spotify.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with an interaction between `kdocker` and "Session Restore" settings, when on KDE Plasma the system is set to re-launch the programs that were running at logout.

I have noticed that after adding the login script the problem was absent at *first* logout/login because `krunner` was not yet running at logout. At next logout it was running, and was thus "restored" at login, resulting in a supplementary `kdocker` process running on top of your script.

(I also want to start a program (`blueman-manager`) minimized to dock (more than that, I need its window *open*, but docked, in order to fix this [odd](https://askubuntu.com/q/1425258/925128) problem: a `bluedevil` [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477442) in fact) and I can do it with a much more simple script, which only contains the line `kdocker blueman-manager`.
My script, as well as more complex scripts, like yours, were having the problem you described, until I have disabled that option.)

Another solution (in case you *must* use the option to restore your session) is to add `kdocker` to a list of exceptions when session is restored.

[image]